# How to detect page opacity?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's imagine someone is loading my website in an iFrame, and they've set the iFrame opacity to 0, what JavaScript can I use to detect my page currently has an opacity of 0?

Comment: I honestly don't think that is possible

Comment: None at all of course, because Same Origin Policy.

Comment: the question could be "Accessing iframe from its source"

Answer (score 3):

None.

The opacity belongs to the frame, not to your site. The same origin policy prevents you from accessing the parent DOM to get details of the frame.

If you are concerned about clickjacking attacks, consider [x-frame-options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) as a defence.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if($('element').css('opacity') == 0) {
    doSomething();
}
```

To detect the opacity

Comment: But the element CSS on my website will not be 0, right? You're talking about detecting the CSS opacity on the parent iFrame? Or am I misunderstanding?